# Write a pandas dataframe to Teradata using Teradata.UdaExec

Tags: python, pandas, teradata

I am connecting to Teradata from python using UdaExec. I am able to read data successfully. Can anyone tell me how to create a table in Teradata from a pandas dataframe.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

As you able to connect to teradata using udaExec, you can create table in teradata using:

```
session.execute("CREATE TABLE tablename (column1 datatype, column2 datatype,column3 datatype, columnN datatype)")
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. How do i write a dataframe to teradata

Comment: Pls try this from pandas.io import sql df.to_sql(con=con, name='db_name.table_name', if_exists='replace', index = 'False')

Answer (score 0):

did you try pandas to_sql?

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#

This function needs SQLAlchemy as well, so in advance you should 'pip install sqlalchemy-teradata'.